# Reload angular component with button click

Tags: javascript, angular, components, refresh, router

I working on a angular 8 application. In that application I want to **reload a component, when a button clicked which is inside of another component.** I found a way to do that with router, first navigate to sample component and then navigate to actual component as shown in below code.

```js
this.router.navigateByUrl('/SampleComponent', { skipLocationChange: true });
this.router.navigate(["yourLandingComponent"]);
```

But in this application I don't have used router. This is simple, single page application. I have used `ngIf` to render components as shown in below.

```js
<div class="row main-wrapper">
    <app-section-rental class="container-fluid p-0" *ngIf="tabset.tab0"></app-section-rental>
    <app-section-insuarance class="container-fluid p-0" *ngIf="tabset.tab1"></app-section-insuarance>
    <app-section-additionals class="container-fluid p-0" *ngIf="tabset.tab2"></app-section-additionals>
    <app-section-optionals class="container-fluid p-0" *ngIf="tabset.tab3"></app-section-optionals>
    <app-price-breakdown class="container-fluid p-0" *ngIf="tabset.tab4"></app-price-breakdown>
</div>
```

So I want to know how to reload my component with a button click, which is inside of another component.

I also found another way to do this with angular subscription. But the problem is I that subscription get an element, I don't have to change any state which make any change in HTML. So I don't know whether my component get reloaded or not. Is it compulsory to do any change in DOM element, in order to reload a component ?

Comment: Hi, Welcome to SO. Please [Read how to ask Question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: @hackerbuddy, you can has a function "refresh", call it in ngOnInit and call it in the (click) of the button. Well, it's a general idea. really I dont' understant so much what is: "refresh a component"

Comment: @KrunalShah thanks dude... that's really helped..!

Comment: @Eliseo thanks dude... It should be reload... I change it...  But the problem is My button is in a another component. So I can't call ngOnInit of a component from another component

Comment: If there are a parent-child relation, just emit a value using a `@Output() refresh=new EventEmitter<any>()` like the docs say https://angular.io/guide/component-interaction#parent-listens-for-child-event

Answer (score 0):

You could use Obersavables from `rxjs`.
This Observable contains the data displayed/updated in you component.

```
private _testSubject = new BehaviorSubject<string>('old data');
testObservable$: Observable<string> = this._testSubject.asObservable();
```

The following function will update your data:

```
public refresh(){
   this._testSubject.next('new Data');
}
```

Call this function on you refresh-button's `onClick`.
And finally you can use your Observable in your components html like that:

```
<div>
   {{(testObservable$|async)}}
</div>
```

Hope that helps!

**EDIT:**

As I noticed in your comments, your refresh button is in an parent component. In this case you could implement your observable in your parent component and work with an input in your comopnent:

```
  @Input()
  yourObservable: Observable<string>;
```

and in your parent component:

```
<app-your-compomemt [yourObservable]="testObservable$"></app-your-compomemt>
```

Comment: Thank you dude... But I tried the same with Subject. But the problem is I don't change any thing in DOM element of that component. So just because of changing state of a component, without do any change to DOM element will my component be reloaded.

Comment: @hackerbuddy you could use '@Input' into your component and manipulate your Obersavble/Subject from your parent component as mentioned in my edit